# Serial communication : Send a list from Python3 to Arduino

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I don't manage to deal with my problem even if I have read a lot about it on internet these last few days.
I try to communicate a variable length list from my Python3 program to my Arduino Leonardo.
Actually the length of these lists is variable but there are only three possible length :

```
first possibility : [0, 0, 1, 176, 1, 0, 0]
second possibility : [0, 1, 11, 255]
third possibility : [0, 2, 0]
```

(most of the values inside these lists are variables)

My Python3 code :

```
with Serial(port = port, baudrate=9600, timeout=1, writeTimeout=1) as port_serie :
  if port_serie.isOpen() :
    for value in Datas_To_Send : #Envoi des données
      s = struct.pack('!{0}B'.format(len(Datas_To_Send)), *Datas_To_Send)
      port_serie.write(s)
```

This code sends binary values like this one :

```
b'\x00\x00\x01\xb0\x01\x00\x00'
(the original list to send was : [0, 0, 1, 176, 1, 0, 0])
```

The problem is that I absolutely don't know how to find back my original list of values with my Arduino code...

My Arduino code (quite basic) :

```
void changeSettings() {
  if ( Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    int byte_read = Serial.read() ;
    Serial.println(byte_read, DEC) ;
```

The output of this code is a pure conversion of each character from the ASCII to the Decimal...

Output (for the binary value I gave as example) :

```
98
39
92
120
48
48
92
120
48
48
92
120
48
49
92
120
98
48
92
120
48
49
92
120
48
48
92
120
48
48
39
10
```

Do you have any idea to find the first list back ?

Thank you

Comment: If you know what ASCII means, you already have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution thanks to @MarkSetchel's and Olmagzar's (Discord user) tips.

Python3 code :

```
if Datas_To_Send :
    long = len(Datas_To_Send)
    Datas_To_Send.insert(0, long)
  
    with Serial(port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem14101', baudrate=9600, timeout=1, writeTimeout=1) as port_serie :
        if port_serie.isOpen() :
            s = struct.pack('!{0}B'.format(len(Datas_To_Send)), *Datas_To_Send)
            port_serie.write(s)
            port_serie.close()
```

So I add list length directly at the first position of my list "Datas_To_Send".
Like that I just have to read it first on Arduino's side to know how many items I have to read.

Arduino code :

```
void changeSettings() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
        unsigned char len = Serial.read();
        unsigned char Datas[len] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) 
        {
            unsigned char byte_read = Serial.read();
            Datas[i] = byte_read ;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to transmit either 7, 4 or 3 values, correct?

Are all the values under 256?

So, i would send 1 byte that is either 7, 4 or 3 followed by either 7, 4 or 3 bytes of the list's elements. If any item in your list is greater than 255 and less than 65,536 you'll need to send 2 bytes per element.

Comment: That's exactly right. 7, 4 or 3 values all less than 256.

What you suggest is to send a first byte informing the number of elements of the list to then allow to read it on the Arduino side ?

If that's the case, the problem is that even if I know its length, I don't know how to recuperate it correctly with the Arduino code to find my original list back.

Comment: You read 1 byte. If it is 3, you read 3 more bytes. If 4, you read 4 more bytes. And so on. Then convert each additional byte you read into an integer and you have your list.